# Set Changed Size During Iteration During Update Function

Tags: python, set

I have a problem where my set is changing size during iteration. I want to remove items from a set if they fulfill the condition of the predicate, *p*, but when I remove it from the set it stops the iteration. How do I remove items from the set without stopping the iteration?

Here's my current code ...

```
    # A Black_Hole is a Simulton; it updates by removing
#   any Prey whose center is contained within its radius
#  (returning a set of all eaten simultons), and
#   displays as a black circle with a radius of 10
#   (width/height 20).
# Calling get_dimension for the width/height (for
#   containment and displaying) will facilitate
#   inheritance in Pulsator and Hunter

from simulton import Simulton
from prey import Prey


class Black_Hole(Simulton):

    def __init__(self, posX, posY, width, height, radius):

        Simulton.__init__(self, posX, posY, width, height);
        self.radius = radius;

    def contains(self, obj: Prey):
        ox, oy = obj.get_location();
        x, y = self.get_location();
        finX = x - ox;
        finY = y - oy;

        return abs(finX) <= self.radius and \
            abs(finY) <= self.radius and type(obj) not in [Black_Hole];

    def display(self, board):
        x, y = self.get_location();
        board.create_oval(x - self.radius, y - self.radius,
                          x + self.radius, y + self.radius,
                          fill = 'black');

    def update(self, model):
        for obj in model.find(self.contains):
            model.remove(obj);
```

The problem lies in the update function. It accesses another class's function and passes a predicate through. The predicate returns a set of values that returned true. I want to remove those values from the set so that they are updated on a GUI.

Comment: What type of object is `model` here? Does that type have methods to remove multiple values? How does `model.find()` iterate over the set you then remove from with `model.remove()`?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a copy of the `model.find()` results:

```
for obj in set(model.find(self.contains)):
    model.remove(obj)
```

There may be more efficient ways to do what you want, but you didn't post enough detail about the class implementing `model`.

Answer (score 0):

I got it(: I just made a copy of the set as someone mentioned and then removed items from that, and then set the original set to the new one.